# Deeplearning4j Autoencoder

Tags: autoencoder, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I couldn't find any full example of an autoencoder in DL4J documentation. I see a good general description of Autoencoders [here](https://deeplearning4j.org/stackeddenoisingautoencoder) with a small piece of code for just the MultiLayerConfiguration, but the code is not full. Is there any full example where a dataset is loaded, pre-processed and then inserted into the network and a prediction is generated? For example, an example working with the [Movielens](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/) dataset, or any other. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You have an example of a deep auto encoder using the mnist dataset here:

https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/deeplearning4j/reference/auto-encoders

With code here:

https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/quickstart/modeling/feedforward/unsupervised/MNISTAutoencoder.java

Comment: Thank you. Is there some Autoencoder reference where we can import a CSV file and do the pre-processing before inserting it into the model?

Comment: To make it clearer. In the example you shared, which is a great refernce for the model, the dataset is downloaded and no processing is done on it. It is directly fed to the network. Consider we have the following format where we need to remove the "timestamp" column for example and then feed the CSV to the network: [User,Movie,Rating,Timestamp].

Comment: You can't expect there to be examples for every possible use case. There are for CSV reading though. I think you will have to write your own DataFetcher and wrangle the data that way.

Comment: -> 404 not found